# How to get the correct start and end of the day in local timezone when the server is on UTC in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timezone, date-fns

I've got server that run the on UTC timezone, but I need to get data range on local timezone, the data have `collectTime` attribute that has unix timestamp. So I just need to get the start and end of day of the locale to get correct data represent this day

This is what I tried :

```js
const { startOfDay, endOfDay, getTime, subDays } = require("date-fns");
const { utcToZonedTime } = require("date-fns-tz");

const timezone = "Asia/Jakarta";

const correctLocalStartDate = 1685379600000;
const correctLocalEndDate = 1685465999999;

const selectedUnixTime = subDays(new Date(), 1).getTime();

const localDate = utcToZonedTime(selectedUnixTime, timezone);

const localStartDate = getTime(startOfDay(localDate));
const localEndDate = getTime(endOfDay(localDate));

console.log(
  {
    isItCorrect: localStartDate === correctLocalStartDate,
    correctDate: new Date(correctLocalStartDate),
    systemDate: new Date(localStartDate),
  },
  "Start Date"
);

console.log(
  {
    isItCorrect: localEndDate === correctLocalEndDate,
    correctDate: new Date(correctLocalEndDate),
    systemDate: new Date(localEndDate),
  },
  "End Date"
);
```

Will return

```js
{
  isItCorrect: false,
  correctDate: 2023-05-29T17:00:00.000Z,
  systemDate: 2023-05-30T07:00:00.000Z
} // Start Date

{
  isItCorrect: false,
  correctDate: 2023-05-30T16:59:59.999Z,
  systemDate: 2023-05-31T06:59:59.999Z
} // End Date
```

But the `localStartDate` (printed on `systemDate`) are still wrong since it's not on the correct start of local date that I'm using. How do I get the correct unix timestamp for start and end day on locale date time?

Comment: Tips to run the script in UTC you can do this `env TZ='UTC' node index.js`

Comment: You use a function `utcToZonedTime` but your requirement sounds as if you need it vice versa: convert a local time (for example, midnight) to UTC.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I don't understand, you mean that I should not use `utcToZonedTime` ? Yup I wanted to get start and end of day in local time and convert it to unix timestamp. Because I got range of data that have unix timestamp, I only need the data range for my local time, thats why I need start and end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the original answer has been deleted, I dont know why. But the answer is :

The `endOfday` and `startOfDay` doesn't use timezone date (it's always UTC, because my server are on UTC). The correct way to use it would be :

```js
    const localStartDate = getTime(
      zonedTimeToUtc(startOfDay(localDate), timezone)
    );
    const localEndDate = getTime(zonedTimeToUtc(endOfDay(localDate), timezone));
```